# SQL Server: Replace Arabic Character in Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sqltransaction

I would like to replace Arabic character in select statement with another Arabic character in SQL server, example query:

```
select replace(ArabicName, 'أ', 'ا') as ArabicName from dataIndividual;
```

But it does not replace, the reason probably that SQL server does not read the character as **Unicode** but as **ASCII** (*I guess*).

Is there a way to pass a Unicode characters for `replace` function?

Note: *I already tried `collate` after the Arabic character.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix your string with `N`

```
select replace(ArabicName, N'أ' , N'ا') as ArabicName 
from dataIndividual;
```

Comment: Ops! That is totally right! Don't know how I forgot that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont know why im getting " Incorrect syntax near 'N' " ERROR!!

Comment: Thanks, in my case I need to cast to nvarchar(max) as shown below ,REPLACE(CAST( [ayahText] as nvarchar(max)),CAST( N'بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ' as nvarchar(max)),'') as dd